# Pass string for error message using Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Error message using Data Annotations but in ErrorMessage I want to pass variable string but when I do that it gives error when project is build.

```
string errorMessage="Something happened";

[Remote("IsTimeValid", "Account", AdditionalFields = "TaskDate,TodoID", ErrorMessage =errorMessage)]
public string Time{get;set;}
```

Is there any way to show variable value in ErrorMessages?

Comment: @Ehsan can you please answer my query.?

Comment: i think its not possible, but may be possible i never did something like this

Comment: You can only assign constant values to attribute properties so what you're attempting is not possible. Why are you trying to set the error message from the variable? there might be another way to achieve the same thing

Comment: @Martin i want to convey my user that this error is according to its timezone.. Basically static method from baemodel return string for which timezone user try to insert date. I want that static method in place of ErrorMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the ability to do pretty much exactly what you're asking (in your comment).

You set `ErrorMessageResourceType` to be the type which contains the static property and you set `ErrorMessageResourceName` to be the name of the property on the class

E.g.

```
public class Time
{
    [Remote("IsTimeValid", "Account", AdditionalFields = "TaskDate,TodoID", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Time), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidTimeZoneMessage")]
    public string Time{get;set;}

    public static string InvalidTimeZoneMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return "You have the wrong timezone";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am using const string field but not succeeeded with that.
It is pretty nice Answer :)