# How to set data annotation ErrorMessage string value from static method that returns string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am using global static method for localization purpose. This static method takes Resource Name and returns string Resource Value for it. This method is like this

```
public static string GetResourceValue(string ResourceName)
{
    return "StringValue";
}
```

I am accessing this method from my View like this

```
@MyClass.GetResourceValue("ResourceName")
```

and it returns string value to display. This works properly but how do I use this same method to use in my Model? Is there any way to set ErrorMessage value from this static method some thing like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage=MyClass.GetResourceValue("ResourceName"))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sadly, there seems to be no way of what you are proposing.

Comment: Any alternate solution for it?

Comment: I tried using config. But it's not working. Gives the following error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

Comment: The attribute must be a constant. You have to specify the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solution to this problem using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534783/error-message-using-data-annotations-but-in-errormessage-i-want-to-pass-variable)

I just created new class with static properties like this

```
public class LocalizedErrorMsg
{
    public static string NameRequiredMsg
    {
        get
        {
            return MyClass.GetResourceValue("NameRequiredMsg");
        }
    }
}
```

and in data annotation passed ErrorMessageResourceName as static property name and ErrorMessageResourceType as class name like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameRequiredMsg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LocalizedErrorMsg))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

problem is that it need to create extra class that stores static properties which returns error message from my localization global static method. I searched but I didn't get solution other than this.